# use one list to replace values in another

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, na, mapply

How can I use one list of vectors to replace the values in another list of data frames? Ultimately, I want a data frame that has certain values replaced by NAs.

```
list1 <- list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
list2 <- as.list(data.frame(mat.or.vec(6, 3)))

desired_ouput <- data.frame(mat.or.vec(6, 3))
desired_ouput[1:2, 1] <- NA
desired_ouput[3:4, 2] <- NA
desired_ouput[5:6, 3] <- NA
desired_ouput
```

[image]

Comment: `x <- rep(0, max(unlist(list1))); sapply(list1, function(i){x[i] <- NA; x})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that uses `Map`:

```
myDf <- data.frame(Map(function(x, y) {y[x] <- NA; y}, list1, list2))
names(myDf) <- paste0("X", 1:ncol(myDf))
```

which returns

```
myDf
  X1 X2 X3
1 NA  0  0
2 NA  0  0
3  0 NA  0
4  0 NA  0
5  0  0 NA
6  0  0 NA
```

Map produces a list object, which is wrapped in `data.frame` to return the proper object. However, it is necessary to provide a nicer name to each column with `names`.

Answer (score 4):

This may not look obvious, but is rather efficient (**fully vectorized, with no `for` loop or `*apply`** family)

```
y <- unlist(list2, use.names = FALSE); m <- length(list2[[1]])
x <- unlist(list1) + rep((0:(length(list1)-1)) * m, lengths(list1))
y[x] <- NA; attr(y, "dim") <- c(m, length(y) / m)
as.data.frame(y)

#   V1 V2 V3
# 1 NA  0  0
# 2 NA  0  0
# 3  0 NA  0
# 4  0 NA  0
# 5  0  0 NA
# 6  0  0 NA
```

Why do this? From OP's statement, I can know that `list1` can be ragged, while `list2` can not (because later OP wants to turn the updated `list2` into a data frame). Therefore, there is a way to use fast indexing to solve this problem.

---

Thanks to @alexis_laz's comment, that I could use

```
y <- unlist(list2, use.names = FALSE)
```

instead of

```
y <- unname(unlist(list2))
```

Comment: The `unname(unlist())` could be replaced by `unlist(, use.names = FALSE)` to, also, avoid the cumbersome process of `unlist` creating not needed "names". Also, I guess that -unless `list2` has `length(list2) >> lengths(list2)`- it could, instead, be more efficient to keep the "list"-y structure and replace with a loop instead of creating an "atomic" and, then, splitting it to chunks for the "data.frame" columns

Answer (score 3):

Just use for:

```
list1 <- list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
df <- data.frame(mat.or.vec(6, 3))

for(i in 1:length(list1)) {
  df[list1[[i]], i] <- NA
}
# df
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1  NA  0  0
# 2  NA  0  0
# 3  0   NA 0
# 4  0   NA 0
# 5  0   0  NA
# 6  0   0  NA
```

Comment: thank you Bulat, I was trying to learn more about functional approaches, such as rapply, mapply and lapply.

Comment: To avoid the `"[<-.data.frame"` overhead (and since OP has `list2` as a "list") you could, just, use `for(i in seq_along(list2)) is.na(list2[[i]]) = list1[[i]]` and, then, wrap `list2` with `as.data.frame`